# Easy way for merging two meshes

Tags: modeling

Is there a way of merging together two flat meshes A & B so that all vertices/edges/faces of B become part of A. Mesh B is a simple overlay (road) on top of mesh A (terrain). For performance reasons, this needs to end up as a single low poly mesh with a single material texture. Therefore road polygons and other parts of terrain need to have clear boundaries within the mesh to correctly unwrap.

Now I have the terrain and roads as two separate meshes. Merging these as two objects (Ctrl+J) will glue the two together but leave multiple overlapping faces fighting with each over at z. I believe I can also use Shrinkwrap to put one on top another with some offset but this is not what I'm looking for. Is there a way to simply weld one mesh with the other so that the whole structure becomes a single mesh with no duplicates or overlaying/double faces? Without manually tracing the pretty large roads mesh?

Thanks for any hints

Comment: Have you tried with a knife project ?

Comment: Thanks Softyoda! Just tried knife project and it sort of works. I mean it does the trick but you need to do a bit of leg work to set it up.

I was hoping there is something super simple like an out of the box boolean AND or something that can project one onto the other by simply selecting the two and running a magic command (not taking into account current camera view projection).

Still, this is the best solution out of all sorts of things I tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: @voidcoder if I get paid to do an addon that does what you want I can do that would be the fastest solution and in a couple of clicks